# Unit test that sequence of calls are made in order when the method called is the same but with different arguments (Jasmine & Angular)

Tags: javascript, angular, unit-testing, jasmine, observable

I have an Angular service with a method that makes a call to a method in an httpService that returns an observable.
Once that method returns success, a series of parallel calls are made to the same method of the httpService but with different params to save some images.

I am trying to unit test that the calls are made in the right order and with the right params.
When I try to use spies and .toHaveBeenCalled() I only get the 1st call recognised by Jasmine.

I am assuming it has something to do with timing but I am lost and can't find any examples of this use case. Any guidance will be appreciated.

Edit: the code works 100%, my issue is just how to write unit tests for the sequence calls.

// Service

```
// HttpS is a custom service that makes HTTP requests
constructor(private httpS: HttpS) {
}

save(params: {images: any[]}): Observable<any> {
   return this.saveEntry(params);
}

private saveEntry(params: {images: any[]}): Observable<any> {
  return this.httpS.put('url', {something: 'something'}).pipe(
    // once this request is successful, make parallel requests
    concatMap(() => {
      const reqs = [];
      params.images.forEach(image => {
        reqs.push(this.saveImage({ image }));
      });
    
      return forkJoin(reqs);
    })
  );
}

private saveImage(data: {image: any}): Observable<any> {
  return this.httpS.put('url',{imgData: data.image});
}
```

// Test

```
describe('save', () => {

  it('should make a PUT request with something, then on success multiple parallel PUT requests with imgData', () => {

   spyOn(httpService, 'put').and.callFake(() => cold('-a|', { a: {} }));
   service.save(data).pipe(take(1)).subscribe();
   
   // The mock data I'm passing has 3 images so it results in 1 call first, then 3 in parallel, 1 for each image, but this test says it has been called just once.
   expect(httpS.put).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(4);

   // Trying .toHaveBeenCalledWith() but obviously that fails too

  })
})
```

Comment: In your code `saveEntry` gets passed `params` but they are not being accepted. Also, there is no `images`-iterable defined. Is this a copy-paste accident or your actual implementation? The latter would most definitely explain the problem.

Comment: @PhilippMeissner thanks for this. Sorry, I copied-pasted but removed some code to avoid non-relevant clutter, but forgot some important bits.
I should clarify the code works, so I am certain there is nothing wrong with the code itself, it's just a matter of how to write unit tests for it.

Answer (score 1):

I think it has to do with `subscribe` running at a later point in time than your assertions (due to asynchronous nature).

Try this:

```
describe('save', () => {

  it('should make a PUT request with something, then on success multiple parallel PUT requests with imgData', (done) => { // add done to tell Jasmine when you're done with unit test

   spyOn(httpService, 'put').and.callFake(() => cold('-a|', { a: {} }));
   service.save(data).pipe(take(1)).subscribe(response => {
     expect(httpS.put).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(4); // make assertion once the response comes back
     done(); // call done to let Jasmine know you're done with the test
   });
  
  })
})
```

Comment: Thanks so much! that indeed solved the issue.
Is it necessary to add the done()? Does it just make Jasmine not wait to timeout and as a result makes the test run faster?

Comment: The done is needed in this case. Waiting for the timeout will take longer and cause your unit tests to fail (not calling done) and not having done in the callback, the expect call inside of the subscribe will not run because of the asynchronous nature of subscribe.